# Converting Observable<B> to object B

Tags: angularjs, typescript, rxjs, angular2-services

I am using Angular 2 with RxJs. I get the following compilation exception,

```
[ts]
Type 'Observable<Observable<B>>' is not assignable to type 
'Observable<B>'.
  Type 'Observable<B>' is not assignable to type 'B'.
    Property 'id' is missing in type 'Observable<B>'.
```

Below is the code in question. I can't really change the method signature for 'getB' since I am overriding it. The base method does not need the 2nd API call to fill children, hence overriding.

```
export interface A {
   b: B;
}

export class B {
   cList: C[];
}

export interface C {
   name: string;
   type: string;
}

getB(): Observable<B> {
   let entries = <A[]> []; // get A[] via an server call
   // in this case entries will have only one element in the array  
   return this.loadBChilds(entries[0])
     .map(e => e.b);
}

loadBChilds(a: A): Observable<A> {
   // API call to fetch childs
   // set childs to a.b.List
   return this.rest.get('someapi')
     .map(res => {
       res.record.map(r => this.setData(r));
       return a; 
     });
}
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

TIA

Comment: Post your real code. This can't be correct. loadBChilds() returns a, which is of type A, although it's supposed to be Observable<A>.

Comment: @JBNizet - True, but i am returning it from a context of a rest call, so it ends up as Observable<A>. I've updated the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this. The fix was to collapse the first array being received from the first API via a flatMap and then use that for subsequent API call.

```
getB(): Observable<B> {
   return this.rest.get('firstapi')
     .flatMap(res => {
         let entries = res.record
              .map(record => this.getEntry(record));
         return this.loadBChilds(entries[0])
          .map(e => e.b);
     });
}
```